# macOS Catalina Stop iOS Update Reminders

Tags: ios, macos-catalina

is there a way to stop the iOS Update Notfication feature that is built into Catalina?

[image]

as this is becoming beyond frustrating I haven’t found any clues anywhere on how to disable this.

and please no answers or questions regarding *why don’t you update* etc... that’s not an answer I am seeking or want to be questioned about.

also ejecting my phone is not a permeant solution, I literally want to disable this function.

Comment: "ejecting my phone is not a permeant solution" so I'm assuming your phone is connected to the Mac via USB?

Comment: yes i have it docked next to my mac 24/7